# Mule https call with string payload with query string and HTTP POST method

Tags: amazon-web-services, mule, esb, middleware

I am new to ESB mule. I have tried to reach https url using ESB mule.

For my request i have to build the URL and POST content.

Building URL -
I have prepared the value and set it in the java string. This was mapped in the config file using - setInvocationProperty.

Post content :
Post content is the string message.

When i run the program i am getting error message saying

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided

In my java file, i have lines to print the query string value and the payload in console.
When I hit the url with post content written in console using postman chrome extension, i am getting successful response.

But with ESB mule i could not get the successful response.
Could you please show some light to fix this issue ?

Here I have pasted my ESB mule configuration file content.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:wmq="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/wmq" xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/wmq http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/wmq/current/mule-wmq-ee.xsd">

<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8084" basePath="/mule" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="mws.amazonservices.com" port="443" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" protocol="HTTPS" >
        <http:proxy host="proxy.aaa.com" port="8080" username="John" password="pass"/>
    </http:request-config>
<flow name="secondflowFlow">
<http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <custom-transformer class="com.mule.URLBuilding.BuildURL" doc:name="Java"/>
        <set-payload value="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
<http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" method="POST" path="/Products/2011-10-01" doc:name="Amazon_Call_HTTPS">
<http:request-builder>
                <http:query-param paramName="MarketplaceId" value="#[flowVars.strMarketplaceId]"/>
                <http:query-param paramName="ASINList.ASIN.1" value="#[flowVars.strASINListASIN1]"/>
                <http:query-param paramName="AWSAccessKeyId" value="#[flowVars.strAWSAccessKeyId]"/>
                <http:query-param paramName="Action" value="#[flowVars.strAction]"/>
                <http:query-param paramName="SellerId" value="#[flowVars.strSellerId]"/>
                <http:query-param paramName="MWSAuthToken" value="#[flowVars.strMWSAuthToken]"/>
                <http:query-param paramName="SignatureVersion" value="2"/>
                <http:query-param paramName="Timestamp" value="#[flowVars.strtimestamp]"/>
                <http:query-param paramName="Version" value="#[flowVars.strVersion]"/>
                <http:query-param paramName="Signature" value="#[flowVars.strsignature]"/>
                <http:query-param paramName="SignatureMethod" value="#[flowVars.strSignatureMethod]"/>
</http:request-builder>
<http:success-status-code-validator values="0..599"/>
</http:request>
</flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: Hi. Could you share the request you are using with POSTMAN and the entire error message you are seeing with mule? Thanks.

Comment: The url and payload which i am hitting to amazon is built dynamically.The url i used to post in postman to trigger the message is
[http://localhost:8084/mule]
Post message in post man  - `dummy input message`

After sending this message to mule flow.. flow will generate the actual payload and amazon url. Then it will hit it .. Here i am getting the error message as like below.
`The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.`

Comment: After hitting mule esb URL, in my console i got below URL and POST string which is used to hit amazon.
[https://mws.amazonservices.com/Products/2011-10-01?ASINList.ASIN.1=B002GKGL8M&AWSAccessKeyId=xxxx&Action=GetCompetitivePricingForASIN&MWSAuthToken=amzn.mws.xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx&MarketplaceId=xxxx&SellerId=XXXXXXX&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2015-10-30T15%3A52%3A19Z&Version=2011-10-01&Signature=signaturewithURLencoded]

Comment: Post string is
`POST
mws.amazonservices.com
/Products/2011-10-01
ASINList.ASIN.1=B002GKGL8M&AWSAccessKeyId=xxxx&Action=GetCompetitivePricingForASIN&MWSAuthToken=amzn.mws.xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx&MarketplaceId=xxxx&SellerId=XXXXXXX&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2015-10-30T15%3A52%3A19Z&Version=2011-10-01